# Back button in all the activities of my app

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock

I manage the same menu in all my app.
So, I manage a BaseActivity, and extends each activity in my app with BaseActivity :

```
public class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("");

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();

    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_chat:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aqui va el chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_foto:
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aqui van los settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_sync:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aqui van los settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}


}
```

It s a good thing to avoid writing ActionBar configuration in all the activities.
But right now, I want to add Back button in actionbar for all activities.
I can do it if I write in all activities :

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in the oncreate, and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and adding in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.spg.movil.RutaActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ruta" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.spg.movil.FragmentTabsPdv" />
    </activity>
```

But it won't work if I try to centralize this in BaseActivity.
Is there a way to write just once the back button icon in each activity???

Answer (score 0):

go into your activity and hit ctrl+space then type onBack and hit enter. you can then overide the method for the whole activity.

Comment: I don't want to override onBackPressed, I want to add the back button in the icon, on the actionBar